# How do you add "Percentage of Total" text labels to Altair normalized stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

This is the code I am using to build the bar chart itself:

```js
    bar = alt.Chart(selected_publication_total_subs_df).transform_joinaggregate(
        TotalSubCnt='sum(subscriber_cnt)'
    ).transform_calculate(
        PercentOfTotal='datum.subscriber_cnt / datum.TotalSubCnt'
    ).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('yearmonthdate(as_of_date):O', axis=alt.Axis(title='', labelFontSize=12, labelPadding=10, labelAngle=-45)),
        y=alt.Y('sum(subscriber_cnt)', stack='normalize', axis=alt.Axis(format='%', title='% of Subscriber Count' ,labelFontSize=12, labelPadding=10, titleFontSize=16, titlePadding=20)),
        color=alt.Color('status'),
        opacity=alt.condition(legend_selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.1))
    ).properties(width=1000,height=400).add_selection(legend_selection)
```

It is resulting in this visual:

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify where you want to add the labels? You already have "% of subscriber count" in the axis title. If you would want to add it to each y-label you could use `labelExpr` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64106056/2166823, but I think what you have now is cleaner.

Comment: If you want to put additional labels on bars, and the library does not have an option for it, you can do it with simple JS just after the chart is rendered

Comment: @joelostblom I would like to add the labels inside the bars themselves. Shown similarly here in the altair gallery: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/stacked_bar_chart_with_text.html

But instead of the raw numbers, I would like to show the % of Total

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I'm fairly confident this is possible with the Altair library, I'm just not 100% confident how.

Comment: @msquaredsa Thanks for elaborating, could you include what your code looks like when you try the same strategy as in the example you have linked and what does not work. In your current post I don't see you trying to use `mark_text` anywhere.